# Spring MVC @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
    public void demoServiceMethod()
    {

    }

    @Autowired
    JobOrderService joborderSerivce;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 17 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT")
    public void ScheduledMethod() {

    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/2 0 0 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT")
    public void ScheduledMethod2() {

    }
```

fixed rate is working. It runs every 5 seconds but the next methods doesn't run. Is my cron wrong? I wanted to have a scheduled task everyday 5pm, the other one is a test, everyday 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of giving SUN, MON .... use below cron expression

```
0 0 17 * * ?
```

check for your reference [Cron Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm)